# what should i do pls tell when i am installing laravel

Tags: laravel

[[InvalidArgumentException]

  Could not find package /laravel/laravel/var/www/html/my_laravel with stabil

  ity stable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gPEI.png)

Answer (score 0):

No idea how you're getting that directory in your server, Apache2 defaults to /var/www/html, but either way just follow the Laravel Installation guide using Composer. You shouldn't need many commands to install it after setting up a LAMP stack on your server

LAMP Install: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04

Laravel Install: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6